# Visual Studio's "Docker Debug" fails to install linux package, however release/publish resolves and installs the package

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, apt

I'm using VS2019, and have a perfectly working service deployed in both a manually created docker container, as well as via the stub generated from visual studio. VS's release implementation works without an issue, however when i run the container from VS's debug mode, my service throws exception due to one of its dependencies being missing.

**Dockerfile**:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install handbrake-cli -y //This is the only line which has been added to the VS2019 dockerfile stub.
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

**Observed behaviour under Debug, if I launch docker exec/CLI**:

```
# apt-get install handbrake-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package handbrake-cli
# apt-get update && apt-get install handbrake-cli
...
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
...
# HandBrakeCLI
[14:11:51] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[14:11:51] thread 7eff9c606700 started ("libhb")
Missing input device. Run HandBrakeCLI --help for syntax.

HandBrake has exited.
#
```

As it is clear to see, it appears that my Dockerfile is not applying the line which updates and installs handbrake-cli when in debug mode. I've have tried splitting update and install into a separate run, however the same behaviour persists. At this point I'm a bit confused as to what i'm doing wrong, as the release build does not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cisien in C# Discord:

> I'm guessing VS is skipping the final stage and substituting its own to attach the debugger

Solution was moving the installation to the second line such that:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y handbrake-cli && apt-get clean
```

Similarly suggested using apt-get clean to reduce image size.

Very many thanks to Cisien for his prompt and accurate response!